# How to auto-generate sequence number for particular category task in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

*Sorry I don't know how to ask this question.
example-

categoryname/categoryshortname-1

website/web-1
website/web-2
website/web-3
android/andr-1

1-If there is on category table with field categoryname,id,categorycode.

2-Suppose category name is Website and category code is WEB.

3-Suppose if any user assign task to any other member then he will select category code(WEB) and will assign task.

4-After assigning task category code will get inserted into task table.

5After that if user assign task with category code( ANDR) to same user.

6-Now User to whom task is assigned should see category code as WEB-1 and For android task as Andr2

```
$tasktime = new Tasktime();
$tasktime->TaskTitle = Input::get('tasktitle');
$tasktime->Description_Task = Input::get('taskdescribe');
$tasktime->Estimated_Time = $case;
$tasktime->Task_Status = Input::get('status');
$tasktime->Priority_Task = Input::get('priority');
$tasktime->Assignee_Id = Input::get('Assignee_Id');
$tasktime->categorycode = Input::get('cateorycode');
$tasktime->Task_DueDate = Input::get('duedate');
$tasktime->Task_created_by = Auth::user()->firstname;
$tasktime->Created_User_Id = Auth::user()->id;
$tasktime->tasktype = Input::get('tasktype');
$tasktime->save();
// send mail to assignee id
$assigneeUser = User::find(Input::get('Assignee_Id'));
Mail::send('emails.send', array('TaskTitle' => Input::get('tasktitle'), 'Priority_Task' => Input::get('priority')), function ($message) use ($assigneeUser) {
    $message->to($assigneeUser->email)->subject('verify');
});

return Redirect::to('index')->with('message', 'Email has been sent to assignee related to work');
```

This code is related to category code inserted into task table.

I want category code in sequence such as Web1 Web2 Andr1 Web3 like this if user assign task based on category code.

Help me out please .i have tried hard to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you right, you want to autogenerate slugs for categories like `website/web-{n}`, each subcategory always starts from 1?
Then:

```
$table = $tasktime->getTable(); // table with tasks
$category = Input::get('cateorycode');

$max = DB::table($table)
           ->where('Assignee_Id', Input::get('Assignee_Id'))
           ->where('categorycode', $category)
           ->select('count(id) as sub_count')->first();

$max = ($max != null) ? intval($max['sub_count']) : 0;
$max++;
$generatedSlug = "$category-{$max}";

// web-1, web-2, andr-1, web-3
// [] + web = web-1, web-2, andr-1, web-3, web-4
// [] + andr = web-1, web-2, andr-1, web-3, web-4, andr-2
```

Code not checked, can require slight modification.

**Upd.**

Maybe, more readable solution:

```php
$assignee = Input::get('Assignee_Id');
$category = Input::get('cateorycode');
$max = Tasktime::where('Assignee_Id', $assignee)
               ->where('categorycode', $category)
               ->value('count(id)');

$next = (intval($max) ?: 0) + 1;
$generatedSlug = "$category-{$next}";
```

Comment: @Himanshu, then you should upvote the answer and/or mark it as accepted. Glad I helped you =)